# How can i bind a list of items into kendo grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, kendo-grid, databound

I have a kendo grid which i want to bind the column data. On my model am returning a list which then get populated to the dropdown. Now i want to bind the description
to the grid column. How can i bind the userName column to the grid.

I want to be display userName on the grid but am not getting it.

Model

```
public class usersModel
{
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }

    public List<usersModel> usersList;
}
```

Controller

```
    public ActionResult GetUsers()
    {
        usersModel md = new usersModel();
        string r = ApiBaseUrl + "/GetAllusers" ;
        string resp = JsonGET(r);
        List<usersModel> users = Deserialise<List<usersModel>>.Deserialise(r);

        md.listUsers = users;
        return View(md);

    }
```

View

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<usersModel>()
                                 .Name("Grid")
                                 .Columns(columns =>
                                 {
                                     columns.Bound(cl => cl.usersList.userName).Title("User Name");
                                 })
                                 .Sortable()
                                 .Pageable()
                                 .Scrollable()
                                 .DataSource(data => data
                                 .Ajax()
                                 .PageSize(1)
                                .ServerOperation(false))
                                )
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Are you trying to bind the entire user list to the grid?

Comment: yes i want to bind the enter list to the grid. so user column will have all the users.

Answer (score 1):

To bind a list to a column you can use the ClientTemplate. You can create a JavaScript function:

```
function displayUserList(data) {
    return $.map(data.usersList, function (e) { return e.userName; }).join(", ");
}
```

And call it in the column ClientTemplate :

```
columns.Bound(cl => cl.usersList).ClientTemplate("#= displayUserList(data) #").Title("User Name");
```

Comment: What if you needed something like this:
columns.Bound(cl => cl.SomeValue).Title("Some Value");
columns.Bound(cl => cl.usersList.Foreach( u => u.userName)).Title("User Name");

Comment: I've updated my answer because I think I misunderstood the original question.

Comment: Thank you, I don't think you misunderstood the question at all... But your new answer would solve what OP was trying to do although it is not exactly the same use case as what I was going  for.